# Azure Logic App SQL component asking for server name and database even though it is already specified in SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, azure-logic-apps

I set SQL connection to the server/database, specified user name, and password.
However, when I try to use it in Logic App Designer why do I still have to put the server name and database name again?

The reason I am asking - when I deploy the Logic App job from DEV to PROD in a template and parameters JSON files I can adjust SQL connection. However, that hard-codded server name on the SQL component is redundant and gives me problems during the deployment process.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Details are below...
Here is my database connection details part of the setup connection that already has the server name and database:
[image]

Here I am trying to use the connection in SQL query and still being asked to enter the server name and database
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here I am trying to use the connection in SQL query and still being asked to enter the server name and database I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Yes, that is how Azure Logic App SQL Connector works. Even, if you have an API which contains database and Server-Name you should again mention them in while designing the Logic app.

[image]

Here it is just saying you to use the Server-Name from the API connection, its not showing something unwanted( as this is its behavior). And its even same for Database name.

[image]

**`Example Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

I think you can now understand how the logic app connector work. For further information refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure?tabs=consumption).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. However, during the dev phase, I use the dev server name. But when releasing now I have to change it manually to the production server name that contains the production database? What I did in the meantime - I used parameters to specify the DEV server name. However, when I export the Logic App job, parameters file that gets exported does not contain the parameters I used.